# Структурирование данных JAVA

Tags: java, ооп

Необходимо реализовать программу, в которой будут использоваться все модификаторы доступы - **private, default, protected, public** на трех уровнях наследования. Также необходимо использовать абстрактный класс.

Я сделал пока так, но понимаю, что это ужасный код. Как сделать его более правильным?

```
abstract public class Person {

protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected String gender;
private int empId;

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String gender) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.gender = gender;
}

protected abstract void getInfo();

abstract public String getFirstName();

abstract public String getLastName();

abstract public String getGender();
}
```

подкласс Person

```
import interfaces.Salary;

public class Employee extends Person implements Salary {

private int salary;
protected int experience;

public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, int experience) {
    super(firstName, lastName, gender);
    this.experience = experience;
}

@Override
public void getInfo() {
}

@Override
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@Override
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Override
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

@Override
public void setSalary(int salary) {

}

@Override
public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
}
```

подкласс Employee

```
public class Manager extends Employee {

public int bonus;

public Manager(String firstName, String lastName, String gender, int experience, int bonus) {
    super(firstName, lastName, gender, experience);
    this.bonus = bonus;
}
}
```

Интерфейс

```
public interface Salary {

void setSalary(int salary);

int getSalary();

}
```

Очень сильно торможу из-за нехватки фантазии и опыта разработки

Comment: Если делаете тестовое задание для собеседования, то совет, не используйте модификатор public для свойств объектов. Исключение, использовать public для констант.

Comment: Рекомендую вам почитать про паттерны проектирования, для того чтобы более грамотно использовать абстракции, инкапсуляцию и т.д., и понимать в каких случаях это надо использовать. Отличная книга по этой теме : GoF Design Patterns Using Java